# Collapse other panel when one is clicked within a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, html, panel

I am having issues with a list of menus clicking and hiding other panels when one is clicked and active.

```
    @{int i = 0;}
    @foreach (var levelOne in Model.MenuLevelOne)
    {
     <div class="panel-group" id="accordion_@i">
      <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_@i">
       <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a onclick="leveltwo('@levelOne.MenuLevel')" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne_@i" href="#collapseOne_@i">@levelOne.MenuLevel</a>
        </h4>
       </div>
      <div id="collapseOne_@i" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
     <div class="panel-body">                                                                               
      <ul class="" id="id-@levelOne.MenuLevel"></ul><ul class="filter-categories__list"></ul>
     </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     i++;
     }
```

This will bring a list of Menus so like this with its sub menus :

Fruit

```
   Apple

   Pear

   Grape
```

Veg

```
   Carrot

   Cucumber

   Beetroot
```

Other

```
   Cake

   Chocalte
```

**All these are collapsed on page load which is fine and working**,

Shows as :

```
 Fruit

 Veg

 Other
```

however, when I open one and then open another one they should close.

So for example if I open Fruit, and then I open Veg. Fruit should close and Veg should open.

```
 Fruit

       Apple

       Pear

       Grape

 Veg

 Other
```

This should now open like this like but it is not working.

```
 Fruit


 Veg

       Carrot

       Cucumber

       Beetroot

 Other
```

Both of them stay open. How can I keep one open then close the rest?

Can someone tell me where I am wrong in the code?

Thanks

New error:

[image: New error when i add the scripts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a function to close opened tabs each time one open:

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
        $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () { //Triggered everytime the collapse is show
            $('.collapse.in').each(function () { //select current collapsed (some versions could be .show instead of .in
                $(this).collapse('hide'); //hide previously collapsed
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion_0">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_0">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne_0" href="#collapseOne_0">1</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne_0" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="" id="id-1">
                    <li>Nível 1 - Item 1</li>
                    <li>Nível 1 - Item 2</li>
                    <li>Nível 1 - Item 3</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="filter-categories__list">
                    <li>Nível 1 - Filtro 1</li>
                    <li>Nível 1 - Filtro 2</li>
                    <li>Nível 1 - Filtro 3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion_1">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_1">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne_1" href="#collapseOne_1">2</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne_1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="" id="id-2">
                    <li>Nível 2 - Item 1</li>
                    <li>Nível 2 - Item 2</li>
                    <li>Nível 2 - Item 3</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="filter-categories__list">
                    <li>Nível 2 - Filtro 1</li>
                    <li>Nível 2 - Filtro 2</li>
                    <li>Nível 2 - Filtro 3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion_2">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_2">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne_2" href="#collapseOne_2">3</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne_2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="" id="id-3">
                    <li>Nível 3 - Item 1</li>
                    <li>Nível 3 - Item 2</li>
                    <li>Nível 3 - Item 3</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="filter-categories__list">
                    <li>Nível 3 - Filtro 1</li>
                    <li>Nível 3 - Filtro 2</li>
                    <li>Nível 3 - Filtro 3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Copied the code over and the script however its over lapping each time i click another one... i have attached image above. any idea

Comment: its still showing as class="show collapse" when i click another item

Comment: which bootstrap and jquery version are you using? it's not supposed to have use the class "show" in more recent versions. But you can try to replace `$('.collapse.in')` with `$('.collapse.show')`